# How to embed files into Go binaries

Tags: go, binaries

I have some text file that I read from my Go program. I'd like to ship a single executable, without supplying that text file additionally.
How do I embed it into compilation on Windows and Linux?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use [go-bindata](https://github.com/go-bindata/go-bindata). From the README:

> This tool converts any file into managable Go source code. Useful for
>   embedding binary data into a go program. The file data is optionally
>   gzip compressed before being converted to a raw byte slice.

Comment: This is now sort of obsolete. The generate code does not pass golint and the owner of the repo is not interacting with pull requests. I would be wary of this library

Comment: A new project called [statik](https://github.com/rakyll/statik) seems to do this and has been active more recently.

Comment: This tool seems to be migrated to the new dedicated project - https://github.com/go-bindata/go-bindata, but there are other (and may be better) alternatives mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 137):

### ===== Edit Jan 2021 =====

Starting with Go 1.16, released in Feb 2021, you can use the [`go:embed`](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/embed/) directive:

```
import "embed"

//go:embed hello.txt
var s string
print(s)

//go:embed hello.txt
var b []byte
print(string(b))

//go:embed hello.txt
var f embed.FS
data, _ := f.ReadFile("hello.txt")
print(string(data))
```

### ===== Original answer ======

Since Go 1.4, you can use [go generate](https://blog.golang.org/generate) if you need more flexibility.

If you have more than one text file or the text file may change you might not want to hardcode the text file but include it at compile time.

If you have the following files:

```
main.go
scripts/includetxt.go
a.txt
b.txt
```

And want to have access to the contents of all .txt files in main.go, you can include a special comment containing a go generate command.

#### main.go

```
package main

import "fmt"

//go:generate go run scripts/includetxt.go

func main() {
    fmt.Println(a)
    fmt.Println(b)
}
```

The go generate command will run the script after `go:generate`. In this case it runs a go script which reads all text files and outputs them as string literals into a new file. I skipped the error handling for shorter code.

#### script/includetxt.go

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

// Reads all .txt files in the current folder
// and encodes them as strings literals in textfiles.go
func main() {
    fs, _ := ioutil.ReadDir(".")
    out, _ := os.Create("textfiles.go")
    out.Write([]byte("package main \n\nconst (\n"))
    for _, f := range fs {
        if strings.HasSuffix(f.Name(), ".txt") {
            out.Write([]byte(strings.TrimSuffix(f.Name(), ".txt") + " = `"))
            f, _ := os.Open(f.Name())
            io.Copy(out, f)
            out.Write([]byte("`\n"))
        }
    }
    out.Write([]byte(")\n"))
}
```

To compile all .txt files into your exectutable:

```
$ go generate
$ go build -o main
```

Now your directory structure will look like:

```
main.go
main
scripts/includetxt.go
textfiles.go
a.txt
b.txt
```

Where textfiles.go was generated by go generate and script/includetxt.go

#### textfiles.go

```
package main 

const (
a = `hello`
b = `world`
)
```

And running main gives

```
$ ./main
hello
world
```

This will work fine as long as you're encoding UTF8 encoded files. If you want to encode other files you have the full power of the go language (or any other tool) to do so. I used this technique to [hex encode](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/hex/) png:s into a single executable. That requires a minor change to includetxt.go.

Comment: Nice! I had no idea that function existed. This is so much cleaner than dumping in a string literal in the source.

Comment: Just curious, why do we have to write preprocessor command in comments and then separately run `go generate`? Couldn't `go build` take care of running command when it notices `//go:generate ...` comment?

Comment: As of 2019-07-23, this code does not work for text files that contain backticks. They will either produce syntax errors or allow for code injection, neither of which is desired.

Comment: I'm Go newpie, it gave me undefined a and b by running the main file, the includedtext.go file had been generated successfuly.

Comment: @Bunyk, I found this explanation in a [Go Blog article](https://blog.golang.org/generate):

The latest Go release, 1.4, includes a new command that makes it easier to run such tools. It's called go generate, and it works by scanning for special comments in Go source code that identify general commands to run. It's important to understand that **go generate is not part of go build. It contains no dependency analysis and must be run explicitly before running go build.** It is intended to be used by the author of the Go package, not its clients.

Comment: [Offical docs suggests](https://pkg.go.dev/embed) importing embed package with underscore (blank identifier) as `import _ "embed"` for using `go:embed` directive to load content into a `string` or `[]byte` type of variable. [Discussion on github](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/43217)

Answer (score 13):

**Updated 2023-10-19**

From the author of previously recommended in original answer [mjibson/esc](https://github.com/mjibson/esc/):

> Stop using this and switch to [embed](https://pkg.go.dev/embed) now in the standard library.

**Original answer**

Was looking for the same thing and came across [esc: Embedding Static Assets in Go](https://mattjibson.com/esc/) (by 19 Nov 2014) where author, [Matt Jibson](https://github.com/mjibson), is evaluating 3 other popular packages that claims to do file embedding:

1. [rakyll/statik](http://github.com/rakyll/statik)
2. [jteeuwen/go-bindata](http://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata) (and the new official [go-bindata/go-bindata](https://github.com/go-bindata/go-bindata) and another improved one [kevinburke/go-bindata](https://github.com/kevinburke/go-bindata))
3. [GeertJohan/go.rice](http://github.com/GeertJohan/go.rice)

and explain why he eventually come up with his own package:

4. **[mjibson/esc](https://github.com/mjibson/esc/)**

So after briefly trying them all (in that order) I've naturally settled on Matt's [esc](https://github.com/mjibson/esc/) as it was the only one that was working out of the box *with necessary for me* functionality (HTTPS service in a single executable), namely:

1. Can take some directories and recursively embed all files in them in a way that was compatible with [http.FileSystem](https://golang.org/src/net/http/fs.go?s=2511:2573#L77)
2. **Can optionally be disabled** for use with the local file system for local development without changing the client's code
3. Will not change the output file on subsequent runs has reasonable-sized diffs when files changed
4. Capable of doing the work via `//go:generate` instead of forcing you to manually write additional Go code

The point **#2** was important for me and the rest of the packages for one reason or another didn't work out that well.

From esc's README:

> esc embeds files into go programs and provides http.FileSystem interfaces to them.
>
> It adds all named files or files recursively under named directories at the path specified. The output file provides an http.FileSystem interface with zero dependencies on packages outside the standard library.

Answer (score 5):

check [packr](https://github.com/gobuffalo/packr), its quite friendly to use

```golang
package main

import (
  "net/http"

  "github.com/gobuffalo/packr"
)

func main() {
  box := packr.NewBox("./templates")

  http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(box))
  http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}
```

Comment: If you're looking at the most stars as a measure for software then this is the one.

Comment: Which is going to be superseded by [pkger](https://github.com/markbates/pkger)

Answer (score 5):

With **go1.16**, you can start using **`embed`**, this is standard package which helps you embed static non-go files into your binary

Documentation: https://pkg.go.dev/embed 
Example: https://blog.carlmjohnson.net/post/2021/how-to-use-go-embed/

for **go < 1.16**, you can use **packr**. It's an awesome tool, you can check out more about this at https://github.com/gobuffalo/packr

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [`string literal`](http://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals) to define the text as a constant or variable. String literals are defined by enclosing the string with back-quotes. e.g. `string`.

For example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    const text = `
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit  
amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante 
hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet 
vitae augue. Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem lacinia consectetur. Donec ut 
libero sed arcu vehicula ultricies a non tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ut gravida lorem. Ut turpis felis, pulvinar a 
semper sed, adipiscing id dolor. Pellentesque auctor nisi id magna consequat sagittis. 
Curabitur dapibus enim sit amet elit pharetra tincidunt feugiat nisl imperdiet. Ut 
convallis libero in urna ultrices accumsan. Donec sed odio eros. Donec viverra mi quis 
quam pulvinar at malesuada arcu rhoncus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis 
parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In rutrum accumsan ultricies. Mauris vitae 
nisi at sem facilisis semper ac in est.
`

    fmt.Println(text)
}
```

Comment: Although simpler it doesn't work if your 'file' contains characters like `%`.

Answer (score 2):

I used a simple function to read an external template in a `go generate` run and to generate Go code from it. A function returning the template as a string will be generated. One can then parse the returned template string using `tpl, err := template.New("myname").Parse(mynameTemplate())`

I did put that code to github. You might want to try https://github.com/wlbr/templify

Very simple, but works for me quite well.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @CoreyOgburn comment and this [Github comment](https://github.com/rakyll/statik/issues/18#issuecomment-258438040), the following snippet was created:

```
//go:generate statik -src=./html

package main

import (
    _ "./statik"
    "github.com/rakyll/statik/fs"
)

func statikFile() {
    s, _ := fs.New()
    f, _ := s.Open("/tmpl/login.html")
    b, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(f)
    t, _ := template.New("login").Parse(string(b))
    t.Execute(w, nil)
}
```

and run

```
go generate
```

and subsequently

```
go build
```

should create a binary that contains the files

Comment: Nowadays I would recommend [packr](https://github.com/gobuffalo/packr/tree/master/v2), [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58256664/2777965).