# How to embed Go HTML templates into code?

Tags: html, templates, go

I have a set of templates as files, like `base.html`, `login.html`, `profile.html`, `header.html` and so on. They are structured in folders.

It's fine to have them as separate files during development but when I deploy the app, I'd like to have them all embedded as strings or parsed and compiled templates ready to use from the code as usual.

How should I better make these templates as Go code? So that I don't have to have a `templates` folder in production, but everything in the single executable file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to bundle static resources in a Go program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904441/whats-the-best-way-to-bundle-static-resources-in-a-go-program/28071360#28071360)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17796043/embedding-text-file-into-compiled-executable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to bundle static resources in a Go program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904441/whats-the-best-way-to-bundle-static-resources-in-a-go-program)

Answer (score 11):

With Go 1.16 there would be official `"embed"` package and the following would be possible (*is* possible if you read this after February 2021):

```
//go:embed "mytemplate.tmpl"
var myTemplate string
```

This code embeds `mytemplate.html` at compile time and it becomes available as a string (or as `[]byte` or as a FileSystem, if you wish). No 3rd-party tools or libraries needed.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple solution is to embed templates in string literal inside Go source code.

There is a tool that can help, see [go-bindata](https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata).

I used `go generate` in some of previous projects for this type of operation, see [blog post on go generate command](https://blog.golang.org/generate%20go-generate) for introduction.

Answer (score 1):

As of the Go 1.16 release, there is the //go:embed comment directive.
This allows you to directly embed files in your binary.

Link for draft design of [the go:embed comment directive](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/draft-embed.md)

Link for the [Github issue for go embed with some updates](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/41191)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [go-bindata](https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata) which was already mentioned, there is [go-bindata-assetfs](https://github.com/elazarl/go-bindata-assetfs) which you can use to serve static files from a webserver. It's good for Javascript, CSS, etc.