# Ship Golang binary with dynamic(config.toml) configuration file

Tags: go, compilation

I have a simple go server that works, and gets most of its configuration settings from a `toml` file.
The current process involves restarting the `go build` source every time the settings are changed.
What is the correct/most preferred/tested and working way to ship only binary and the config.toml file?
I am still a newbie when it comes to compiling, and i have been reading a lot of texts and still not having a clear understanding on this issue.
Any useful comments will be appreciated.

Comment: You can pass the config file as a flag to the binary e.g. `<binary> -c config.toml` and set the default in `flag.String("c", "config.toml", "config file")`.

Comment: @weavr , I will be looking into that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Config files aren't meant to be embedded in executables. It'd be better to have them reside alongside executables. Since I couldn't get your point on rebuilding complete app just for reloading configuration, I made up my former sentences presuming you're hardcoding.

If we get to the “reloading” topic, I would surely restart my program or send a signal to re-load the configuration. You don't have to do this, because there is a nice library doing this: https://github.com/spf13/viper. It is easy to use and supports live watching for changes on config file. Besides supporting JSON, YAML, TOML and HCL, it can read from environment variables, remote config systems (like Consul and etcd). It's trusted and used by big projects, such as Kubernetes.

Comment: I actually use viper. I will be testing the live watch functionality today.

Comment: Perfect, it works now. I had to update the config after reload. Now I need it to work with the binary.

Comment: Actually, the assertion that "Config files aren't meant to be embedded in executables" is at best contentious. 
  There are cases where this is a useful thing to do - see here: 
                      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17796043/how-to-embed-files-into-golang-binaries

Comment: @GrahamNicholls They are just not supposed to. Embedding static files to serve directly from the executable inside is acceptable. However configuration is different and does change even if it's not often. I believe they should be loaded at runtime for the best efficiency. There is an architectural pattern that tackles this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/external-configuration-store

Comment: We'll have to agree to disagree.  Sometimes it's extremely useful to embed config.  I'm sure that MS have all sorts of patterns, and in general, that they are worth following.  Just not in every case.

Comment: This was actually the correct answer. It is possible to get it into binary, but it works better alongside binary. I have been using it that way for 4 years.