# How to find a sibling file when the os.Getwd() is different in different environments

Tags: go, aws-lambda

```
myprogram/
 |
 |-main.go
 |-dir1/
     |-data/
         |-datafile.json
     |-runner.go
     |-runner_test.go
```

In `runner.go`, I have a simple function that reads the `datafile.json`. Something like

```golang
   func GetPayload() (string, err) {
            dBytes, dErr := ioutil.ReadFile("dir1/data/datafile.json")
            if dErr != nil { return nil, dErr}
            return dBytes, nil
   }
```

I'm using Go in a Lambda with a structure similar to above. When the Lambda runs in its actual environment, it starts at `main.go`, and then invokes `GetPayload()` from `runner.go`. However, I have a test in a simple worker node machine in `runner_test.go` that also hits `GetPayload()` .

During "normal" execution (from `main.go`) - this works OK. However, when `GetPayload()` is invoked from `runner_test.go`, it errors, saying

> open dir1/data/datafile.json no such file or directory

This makes sense, because during the test, the working directory is the directory that houses `runner_test.go`, which is `data/`, so there is no `dir1` as a child of it. I've been trying to play with using `os.Getwd()` and getting the paths from there like:

```golang
   pwd, _ := os.Getwd()
   dBytes, dErr := ioutil.ReadFile(pwd + "dir1/data/datafile.json")
```

But again, that won't work, because for `runner_test.go` pwd is `user/myname/myprogram/dir1`, but from `main.go`, it turns up as `user/myname/myprogram`.

Any idea how I can find and open `datafile.json` from within `GetPayload()` in any environment? I could pass an optional parameter to `GetPayload()` but if possible, it'd be great to avoid that.

Comment: Is this file static? It's possible that you can embed it.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco , yes - this data file is static, part of the directory. Can you elaborate on how to embed it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file is static (meaning that it doesn't need to change after you build the program), you can embed it into the built program. This means you no longer have to worry about run-time file paths.

```golang
import (
    "embed"
)

//go:embed data/*
var dataFiles embed.FS

func GetPayload() (string, err) {
    dBytes, dErr := dataFiles.ReadFile(dataFiles, "data/datafile.json")
    if dErr != nil { return nil, dErr}
    return dBytes, nil
}
```

Now the files in your `data/` directory are embedded in this variable `dataFiles` which acts as a read-only file system.

For more info:

Read more about embed in the [package documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/embed/) overview.

Read my answer about ["when to use embed"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68012776/11424673)

Comment: Looks like this is for go 1.16 though, and no lower?

Comment: @NateH06 That's correct. It's a new part of the build process, so you need the updated tooling in the new release to use it (plus the embed library in 1.16).

Answer (score 0):

For data files that your program needs during runtime, either use a fixed directory and refer to that, or accept a command line argument or some sort of configuration that tells you where the file is.

When running unit tests, the wd is the directory containing the test file. One convention is to use a testdata/ directory under the directory containing the test, and put all data files there. That way you can refer to that file from the test by using `testdata/datafile.json`.

You can use a copy of the file you need during runtime as your test file, or you can use a symlink from the runtime data file to the test file under the testdata/ dir.

Answer (score 0):

> For data files that your program needs during runtime, either use a fixed
> directory and refer to that

Someone made this suggestion, which I agree with. To that end, you can use
something like this:

```
package main

import (
   "os"
   "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
   d, err := os.UserCacheDir()
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   d = filepath.Join(d, "file.json")
   f, err := os.Open(d)
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   defer f.Close()
   os.Stdout.ReadFrom(f)
}
```

- https://golang.org/pkg/os#UserCacheDir
- https://golang.org/pkg/os#UserConfigDir